# Event ID 8021 The browser was unable to retrieve a list of servers from the browser master

Tags: networking, windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-event-log, windows-sbs

We have a LAN where workstations are randomly losing network connectivity for brief moments of time. The workstations can also take a long time to login to the domain.

During our troubleshooting we have found an error log on a few Windows 7 workstations:

Warning BROWSER 8021    The browser was unable to retrieve a list of servers from the browser master \\random-pc on the network \Device\NetBT_Tcpip_{BBABCDE9-D8A0-4399-93F2-492FE0848B12}. The data is the error code.

What do these errors mean? What computers should have the Computer Browser service enabled, workstations and/or servers?

The environment is a mix of Windows 7 & Windows XP workstations on a Windows Server SBS 2011 SP1 domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't sound like you need the Master Browser service, all your workstations are DDNS compatible, you shouldn't use legacy name resolution options like NetBT or WINS.

Check out this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/135404 (most interesting for you is probably the **WORKAROUND** section, namely turning it off)

Comment: Linkrot. There is no longer a Workaround section. This is why the essentials of that should be in your answer! ; - )